# How does PSE traffic change over time?

Tags: discussion, users, site-statistics

I joined the site 8 years ago now and I'd be curious how things have changed over time. Have we been gaining traffic? Losing traffic? Are there particular seasons or times of year that users flock to the site?

Nothing important, just a curiosity. I think that with 25k reputation I could view this stuff through PSE itself, but I'm still far from there.

Comment: Related: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12881/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [final privilege you can earn](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) is, indeed, access to some internal (i.e.: posts and votes) and google (i.e.: traffic) analytics for the site.

There is, as of right now, no data from before February 2018. (This was caused by some change in Google Analytics, and IIRC it was discussed on Meta Stack Exchange at the time.)

The analytics look like this (with all numbers being weekly aggregates:

[image]

The time axis is, unfortunately, rather useless. I tried to pull it into Excel and it messed with the labels (don't trust them below), but you can use the time axis here to asign specific times to features in the official graph:

[image]

I hope this is useful and/or interesting.

Comment: Did something happen around May 5, 2022? (Using the dates in the bottom plot... at least as a label if it's not the right date...). Seems like a sudden change.

Comment: Yes, Google analytics changed their algorithm. See more near that time on the mother Meta…

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/379047/